# Unexpected token : Javascript jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am novice in the JSP application, where we have to pass a url variable from servlet to JSP page using request.getattribute. While passing the data to the javascript function we are getting error below is

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Please find below the JSP page.

```
    <head>
    <%String urlData=(String)request.getAttribute("urlDataFromServlet");%>

<script type="text/javascript">

     var url=<%=urlData%>;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var referLink = document.createElement("a");
        referLink.href = url;
        document.body.appendChild(referLink);
        referLink.click();

    });
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>

</head>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at the code that is generated... It would be clear as day what the issue is

Answer (score 3):

**You need to wrap this with quotes:**

```
var url="<%=urlData%>";
```

Comment: can we pass the header to the calling server url like <%response.addHeader("userDetails", "header");%>